# Content type query filter by object value

Tags: python, django, generics, django-orm

I use Django 2.0.0 and have the following database structure:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_(u'Name'), max_length=32)

class Domain(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey('projects.Project', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tool_result = GenericRelation('projects.ToolResult')

class ToolResult(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

I want to get all ToolResults filter based on content_type object project.

```
ToolResult.objects.filter(content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Domain), content_object__project__in=[1, 2])
```

I tried like this but it is not working. I have about 500k domain records and 3kk ToolResults records. That makes not possible to iterate objects. How do I can do this effective ?

Comment: What is not working about it?

Comment: You can not follow a `GenericForeignKey` like that, you can however solve the problem in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

We can first query the list of `Domain`s for which the project is in `[1, 2]`:

```
domain_ids = (Domain.objects.filter(project__in=[1, 2])
                            .values_list('id', flat=True))
```

now in a second pass, we can filter on both the `content_type` and `object_id`:

```
ToolResult.objects.filter(content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Domain),
                          object_id__in=domain_ids)
```